# Rendering number to n variable places

Tags: python

Attempting to print pi rendered to inputted decimal places using {:.Nf}

Tried replacing variable N with inputted variable n. Also replacing N with {} and assigning n to that. Also replacing n with {n}.

I'm sure the answer is obvious but I can't seem to see it.

```
from math import pi

# Example input() statement
n = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))

format_string = '{:.nf}'

# Replace this with your own print statement
print(format_string.format(pi))
```

Expecting pi to n decimal places, yet it is returning:

> "ValueError: format specifier missing precision"

which I assume means variable `format_string` is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the variable `n` into the format string is to use an f-string, which was introduced in Python 3.6. The f-string allows `n` to be replaced with its current value. However, this requires braces, and the braces that you currently have in your code will also be interpreted as wanting to replace a variable. So replace those braces with doubled braces.

```
from math import pi

# Example input() statement
n = int(input('Please enter an integer: '))

format_string = f'{{:.{n}f}}'

# Replace this with your own print statement
print(format_string.format(pi))
```

When I run this and input the value `10`, I get the printout

```
3.1415926536
```

If you are running a version of Python before 3.6, let me know and I'll show you how to use the `format` method of strings to get the same effect.

Comment: `print('{:.{}f}'.format(pi,10))` for Python <3.6.  You'll also find you can't reuse the above format string for a different `n` without redefining `format_string`, but you could do `print(f'{pi:.{n}f}')`.

Answer (score 0):

As to your error, it is because `n` is not a valid format-specifier. Of course python can't know you mean your local variable `n`, so you have to tell it that. To keep your code in the same structure, you will need 2-level formatting. Something like:

```py
>>> format_string = '{{:.{n}f}}'.format(n=n)
>>> print(format_string.format(pi))
3.14159265
```

Or simply:

```py
>>> format_string = '{:.{n}f}'
>>> print(format_string.format(pi, n=n))
3.14159265
```

---

I would personnaly get rid of the seperate `format` variable and use it directly as one string in the print.

for `n = 8`:

1. using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/): (Python version >= 3.6)

```py
>>> print(f"{pi:.{n}f}")
3.14159265
```

2. using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting): (Python version >= 2.6)

```py
>>> print("{pi:.{n}f}".format(pi=pi, n=n))
3.14159265
```

3. using old [`%` formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```py
>>> print("%.*f" % (n, pi))
3.14159265
```